# how to style disabled antd picker

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I need to apply a custom style to the disabled the antd range picker.

I have added `className` to the component but the style isn't changing.

```
                        <RangePicker
                          className="my-range"
                          allowClear={false}
                          bordered={true}
                          format="HH:mm"
                          style={{ width: "100%" }}
                        />
```

Styles Css: (need to change color of the text in the box)

```
.ant-picker-disabled.building-ophrs-range {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  .ant-picker-input.ant-picker-input-active {
    color: #224cc0;
  }
}
```

[image]

Codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-20-7-forked-g5ee2t?file=/demo.js

Comment: the Styles CSS you have mentioned above looks like SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to write

```
.ant-picker-disabled.my-range {
  background-color: #008000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do work. Also, works without !important. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure! i recommend to use important coz sometimes Antd force the antd's style during the action. of course it depend on you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ant-picker.my-range.ant-picker-disabled {
    background-color: #008000;
}
```